# Sqs is not sending message also no error shows

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Sending message to sqs is not working, I see no error but the message is not getting send to SQS.
I am trying to run this with local lambda.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.DEV_AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region: process.env.DEV_AWS_REGION
  });

var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});


async function pushToSQS(executed_report_id, report_id, filebatchKey) {

    try {
        const data = {
            executed: "YES",
            id: r_id,
            batch_key: key
        }

        var params = {
            MessageBody: JSON.stringify({data}),
            QueueUrl: process.env.DEV_AWS_QUEUE_URL,
            DelaySeconds: 0
        };


       await sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  

            if (err) {
                console.log('SQS Error', err)
                throw err
                return
            }
        console.log("Successfully Sent the data message to SQS", data.MessageId);
        });


    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

I am calling this function from another function when I am trying to build business logic. Its not getting called directly from `index.js` (main handler)

Why its not working, I mean it has to work, throws no error. Also I am trying to run lambda locally using [local-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local)

NOTE - AWS key and secret has Full rights of access to the SQS.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `sqs.sendMessage` doesn't start the operation. It also does not return a promise, instead returning an `AWS.Request` object, so the `await` there doesn't do anything.

In order to actually start the asynchronous operation and get a promise, your call should be `sqs.sendMessage(params).promise()`.

This is true across the `aws-sdk`, not just in the SQS API.

API Documentation:
[AWS.SQS.sendMessage()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property)
[AWS.Request.promise()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this where I was calling a standard queue with message dedup ids in the request. The call to send to a queue came back with OK but nothing happened.

Removing MessageGroupId and MessageDeduplicationId from the SendMessageRequest object fixed the issue.